# Storing value of UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using time pickers and I want to store the two values to use them in calculating price, store in firebase.

This is my UI to simplify the idea

[image]

The problem is that i don't know which part I can use to store the value of start time and end time (the numbers in UI are written in arabic)

This is my code, can you guide me to the way to store the `UITextField` values?

```
@IBOutlet weak var StartTimeTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var EndTimeTxt: UITextField!

func createTimePicker() {
        
    StartTimeTxt.textAlignment = .center
    EndTimeTxt.textAlignment = .center
    
    //tool bar
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    
    //bar button(
    let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
    toolbar.setItems([doneBtn], animated: true)

    //assign tool bar
    StartTimeTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    EndTimeTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    
    // assign time picker to the txt field
    StartTimeTxt.inputView = StartTimePicker
    EndTimeTxt.inputView = EndTimePicker
    
 
    //time picker mode
    /* StartTimePicker.datePickerMode = .time
    EndTimePicker.datePickerMode = .time*/
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    //First range
    let startTime = Date()
    let startRangeEnd = calendar.date(byAdding: DateComponents(minute: 30), to: startTime)!
    let startRange = startTime...startRangeEnd
    //Second range
    let endTime = calendar.date(byAdding: DateComponents(minute: 1), to: startRangeEnd)!
    let endRangeEnd = calendar.startOfDay(for: calendar.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 1), to: startTime)!)
    let endRange = endTime...endRangeEnd
    StartTimePicker.date = startTime
    StartTimePicker.minimumDate = startTime
    StartTimePicker.maximumDate = startRangeEnd
    EndTimePicker.date = endTime
    EndTimePicker.minimumDate = endTime
    EndTimePicker.maximumDate = endRangeEnd
    if #available(iOS 13.4, *)  {
        StartTimePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        EndTimePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure to understand, but what you must store is start and end times. Text fields are just way to display those.

Comment: yes i mean how to store them in a variable according to my code? should i write let endTime = EndTimeTxt.text ?

Comment: You should keep values in view controller properties then use the pickers/text view delegate method to update them upon changes.